# PHP error when reading for txt file to table

Tags: php

I am getting the following errors

```
Notice: Undefined variable: header in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 27
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 41
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 43
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 44
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 45
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 46
Notice: Undefined variable: sortkey in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 47
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 43
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 44
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 45
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 46
Notice: Undefined variable: sortkey in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 47
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 43
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 44
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 45
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 46
Notice: Undefined variable: sortkey in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 47
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 42
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 43
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 44
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 45
Notice: Undefined variable: sortby in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 46
Notice: Undefined variable: sortkey in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 47
```

With the following code

```
 <span class="style2">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body, th, td, p, small {
    font-family:'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
    font-size:100%;
    color:#757675;
}
small {font-size:90%;}

td, th {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    padding:7px 20px 7px 20px;
}
th {background-color:#a5a5a5; color:#FFFFFF;}

h1 {font-size:120%; color:#558;}
h1 .sortby {color:#855;}
-->
</style>
</span>

<?php
echo '<h1><span class="sortby">'.$header.'</span></h1>
<table cellspacing="5" summary="List of demo fields">
<tr>
<th>Date & Time Added</th>
<th>Products</th>
<th>Keys</th>
<th>Computer</th>
</tr>';

$fp = fopen('key.txt','r');
if (!$fp) {echo 'ERROR: Unable to open file.</table></body></html>'; exit;}

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp,1024); //use 2048 if very long lines
    $row++;
    list ($date, $products, $keys, $computer) = split ('\|', $line);
    if ($sortby == 'Date Added') $sortkey = strtolower($date);
    if ($sortby == 'Products') $sortkey = strtolower($products);
    if ($sortby == 'Keys') $sortkey = strtolower($keys);
    if ($sortby == 'Computer') $sortkey = strtolower($computer);
    $col[$row] = array($sortkey, $date, $products, $keys, $computer);
}

fclose($fp);

$arrays = count($col) - 1;

$loop = 0;
while ($loop < $arrays) {
    $loop++;
    echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$col[$loop][1].'</td>
<td>'.$col[$loop][2].'</td>
<td>'.$col[$loop][3].'</td>
<td>'.$col[$loop][4].'</td>
</tr>';
}

echo '
</table>
 '
?>
```

BUT my table is showing correctly and is doing what i want it to do I dont know why iam getting these errors.

Comment: $header doesn't seem to hold a value. are you meant to include a file that gets stored in the $header variable?

Comment: This question is made because of your laziness. Check every error that explain in a clear way what's the problem. Check lines and other stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no errors in your Code. Tat are notice-messages. They are telling you the following problems with your code:

1. split() is deprecated (You should use another mothod `explode` for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php
2. you sould initialise variables before using them:
   `if(!isset($var)){$var="";`

You may disables these warning. but it would be a better coding-style to remove the warnings, by editing the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help i see where my issue is and will try and resolve them

Answer (score 0):

These are **Notices** and **Warnings**. It depends upon your [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) setting in your PHP INI file.

In your case, you have not declared `$header` before it's first use. Also, `split()` is a deprecated function, you should use `explode()` moving forward.

Although these should be considered and breed best coding practices, as you noted, they are not serious enough to stop your script from running.

Answer (score 0):

The `split` errors tell me that you're running PHP 5.3 but with code written for (probably) 5.2.x. The other errors imply you are referring to undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't have to use split() because it is deprecated, look for a similar function in the php manual.
- You have this variables like `$sortby` not declared
- You have some arrays index missings

I'll let you check by yourself becouse you didn't even tried to check your errors, you just copied and pasted over here because of your laziness.
I told you what are the things that causes the errors, just fix it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to fix the errors

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $row = 0;
    $sortby ='';
    $sortkey='';

echo '<h1><span class="sortby"></span></h1>
<table cellspacing="5" summary="List of demo fields">
<tr>
<th>Products</th>
<th>Keys</th>
<th>Date & Time Added</th>
</tr>';

$fp = fopen('key_QA_N1.txt','r');
if (!$fp) {echo 'ERROR: Unable to open file.</table></body></html>'; exit;}

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgets($fp,1024); //use 2048 if very long lines
    $row++;
    list ($products, $keys, $date) = explode('|', $line);
        if ($sortby == 'Products') $sortkey = strtolower($products);
    if ($sortby == 'Keys') $sortkey = strtolower($keys);
    if ($sortby == 'Date & Time Added') $sortkey = strtolower($date);
       $col[$row] = array($sortkey, $products, $keys, $date);
}

fclose($fp);

$arrays = count($col) - 1;

$loop = 0;
while ($loop < $arrays) {
    $loop++;
    echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$col[$loop][1].'</td>
<td>'.$col[$loop][2].'</td>
<td>'.$col[$loop][3].'</td>
</tr>';
}

echo '
</table>
 '
?>
```